# Protecting servlets and jsps

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am facing a problem here regarding the protection of jsps and servlets. When somebody views page source then s/he can view the signout link in jsp page which should not be shown. For example when somebody will view the page source then it is written that **a href="signout.jsp"** then I think it is unsafe and if somebody will click on that signout link then automatically session is invalidated but it should be totally prohibited. How can I protect the jsp page so that when somebody tries to view page source then s/he cannot view such sensible links? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's so unsafe?  What harm can they cause?

Comment: i do not know but i think so as when ever i am viewing page source of anysite after login i am not seeing logout link, hence. How can i encrypt page source?

Comment: How else is your use going to sign out unless you give them a link like that?

Comment: You can't encrypt page source.  I can view the source on Stackoveflow.  If they aren't encrypting their source, why do you think you need to?  Nobody wants your code.

Comment: @sujit thats not how html can work. the only way you could do it is write your own browser and implement a encryption on the server. Even HTTPS is one way i.e. what prints on the browser can be accessed by anyone while what gets sent to the server is something only server can decrypt. Thats why you dont see whole credit card numbers printed on the browser page as normally server scripts would not do it to prevent it from being public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I protect the jsp page so that when somebody tries to view page source then s/he cannot view such sensible links?

You can't.  The link has to be in the HTML (or something else) delivered to the user's browser, and you cannot prevent a human from getting hold of it.

The correct strategy is to implement server-side checks to stop the supposedly harmful request from being run when it shouldn't be used.  For instance, certain requests should be limited to logged in users, administrators, and so on.

But in this case, what is the harm in the user signing out if he / she wants to?  If you try to prevent it, the user can just close the browser, turn off his PC and walk away.

---

> How can i encrypt page source?

Same answer.  You can't.  The user's browser needs to see the source in unencrypted form in order display it.  Your server's response is delivered to a program running on the user's machine, and you can't stop the programming doing what the user wants.  And that includes showing the user the source of the page in unencrypted form.

Answer (score 1):

Any html that prints to the browser is unsafe, in that sense.

But again its perfectly safe to show signout.jsp I really dont see any issues with that. Why do you think it is unsafe?

If there is a signout then it is perhaps to signout!! And if you click on it you should get signed out.

Comment: @sid...thanks for your reply but can you please tell me how can i encrypt page source? while clicking page source of a site if the page source is being encrypted hence a hacker cannot guess easily whether it contains html or something else. Hence how can i protect it?

Comment: please see comment above on the main question thread. You would have to implement your own browser for that purpose. Browsers are generic so they cannot do what you want specifically for you. Unless you add some kind of add on that decrypts messages which is encrypted on your server with a shared key. VPN normally takes care of this sort of stuff to prevent from prying eyes.

Comment: @sid....thanks for your help..well if it is safe then i am happy...thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong : displaying a link is not unsafe.

Allowing a resource to display sensible data is dangerous, but a logout link is completely harmless.

Displaying login/logout links is a good practice.

Consider if Google was hidding its logout link in Gmail !

Comment: @Jean...ya showing logout is a good practice, i was talking about showing logout link while viewing page source, well i do not think there is any harmful effect when somebody sees logout link in page source as it leads to simply signout.